# How to access a document set using csom?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, csom, document-set

I have already created multiple documents set in a folder, now I want to get those document set I created individually and assign some permission to them,

I just cant seem to be able to retrieve those document set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method to get the document set.

To break the inheritance, you need to use the `BreakRoleInheritance` method.

So, try and modify the below sample code:

```
//assuming that the document set's name is "test"
var docSetFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/testsitecollection/Documents/test");
context.Load(docSetFolder, d => d.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var docSetFolderItem = docSetFolder.ListItemAllFields;
docSetFolderItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var user = context.Web.EnsureUser("domain\\someuser");
//var approverGroup = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Approvers");
var roletypes = context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);

RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context);
collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(roletypes);
docSetFolderItem.RoleAssignments.Add(user, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
//docSetFolderItem.RoleAssignments.Add(approverGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```